# Python mixins with context managers don't solve "super" call correctly

Tags: python, mixins, contextmanager

I am writing a class representing a file. This class has some optional features: normally files are stored in memory, but sometimes there is a need for storing them on disk, sometimes I want to store them as zip files and so on. I decided to use mixins, where I can subclass File class and in case of need add mixins I actually need in some case. In such situation reading/writing to a file is an operations that requires some preparation and some cleanup (I need to zip file, perform some write e.g. and than again zip updated version). For this purpose I wanted to use custom context managers, to ensure these actions are performed even if there's an exception or return statement in the middle of with statement. Here's my code:

```
class File(object):

    def read(self):
        return "file content"

class ZipMixin(object):

    def read(self):
        with self:
            return super(ZipMixin, self).read()

    def __enter__(self):
        print("Unzipping")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        print("Zipping back")


class SaveMixin(object):

    def read(self):
        with self:
            return super(SaveMixin, self).read()

    def __enter__(self):
        print("Loading to memory")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        print("Removing from memory, saving on disk")

class SaveZipFile(SaveMixin, ZipMixin, File):
    pass

f = SaveZipFile()
print(f.read())
```

However, the output is quite disappointing:

```
Loading to memory
Loading to memory
Removing from memory, saving on disk
Removing from memory, saving on disk
file content
```

while it should be:

```
Loading to memory from disk
Unzipping
Zipping back
Removing from memory, saving on disk
file content
```

Apparently, all calls to super in mixins with context managers are not passed "in chain" to all mixins, but rather two times to first mixin, then directly to superclass (omitting intermediate mixins). I tested it both with python 2 and 3, same result. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

### What happens?

The "super" call works as you expect it to work, the `read` methods of both of your mixins are called in the expected order?

However, you use `with self:` in both of your `SaveMixin` and `ZipMixin` classes read methods.

`self` is the same in both cases, resulting in the same `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods beeing used, regardless the declaring class.

According to the method resolution order of the `SaveZipFile` class, the methods of the `SaveMixin` class are used:

```
>>> SaveZipFile.__mro__
(<class '__main__.SaveZipFile'>, <class '__main__.SaveMixin'>, <class '__main__.ZipMixin'>, <class '__main__.File'>, <class 'object'>)
```

**In short** the read methods of your SaveMixin and ZipMixin classes are called in the correct order, but the `with self:` uses the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods of the `SaveMixin`class both times.

### How can this be resolved?

It seems like the `with` statement is not optimal for the usage with Mixins, but a possible solution is using the [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern):

```
class File(object):
    def read(self):
        return "file content"

class ZipDecorator(object):
    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.inner = inner

    def read(self):
        with self:
            return self.inner.read()

    def __enter__(self):
        print("Unzipping")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        print("Zipping back")


class SaveDecorator(object):
    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.inner = inner

    def read(self):
        with self:
            return self.inner.read()

    def __enter__(self):
        print("Loading to memory")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        print("Removing from memory, saving on disk")

class SaveZipFile(object):
    def read(self):
        decorated_file = SaveDecorator(
            ZipDecorator(
                File()
            )
        )

        return decorated_file.read()


f = SaveZipFile()
print(f.read())
```

**Output:**

```
Loading to memory
Unzipping
Zipping back
Removing from memory, saving on disk
file content
```

Answer (score 0):

The `self` that you're passing around is of type `SaveZipFile`.  If you look at the MRO (method resolution order) of `SaveZipFile`, it's something like this:

```
            object
         /    |     \ 
SaveMixin  ZipMixin  File
         \    |     /
           SaveZipFile
```

When you call `with self:`, it ends up calling `self.__enter__()`.  And since `self` is of type `SaveZipFile`, when we look at the MRO paths for that class (going "up" the graph, searching the paths left to right), and we find a match on the first path (in `SaveMixin`).

If you're going to offer the zip and save functionality as mixins, you're probably better off using the `try/finally` pattern and letting `super` determine which class's method should be called and in what order:

```
class File(object):
    def read(self):
        return "file content"

class ZipMixin(object):
    def read(self):
        try:
            print("Unzipping")
            return super(ZipMixin, self).read()
        finally:
            print("Zipping back")

class SaveMixin(object):
    def read(self):
        try:
            print("Loading to memory")
            return super(SaveMixin, self).read()
        finally:
            print("Removing from memory, saving on disk")

class SaveZipFile(SaveMixin, ZipMixin, File):
    pass
```